# What is the value of AIC criterion if RSS is 0?

Tags: data-science-model, accuracy, error-handling, estimators

The AIC formula is :

$AIC = 2k + n Log(RSS/n)$

So if RSS is equal to 0, it is undefined. How do I deal with this? What value should it take?

Comment: So your model has a perfect fit?

Answer (score 1):

RSS = 0 implies that the model is a perfect fit since there was no residual. The limit of the log of 0 is $-\infty$, and since lower AICs are better, and this model is perfect,it makes perfect sense that the AIC should be a negative number such that no number can be lower.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, but the problem is that I am evaluating the AIC fo each fit and then I want to take the mean of these values (I cannot compute the AIC of the model with all the fits together because I have a different number of datapoints for each). So how should I handle this?

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question regarding taking the mean of an AIC across many fits, and how to deal with the case that a given fit is perfect. It's not something that I've heard of before, so I think you would have to provide lots of details and particularly why you're doing it.

Comment: Maybe my approach of taking the mean is wrong. Do you know how could I compute the AIC if for every fit I have a different number of data points?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't compare the AIC between models on different datasets, that's where my understanding of what you're trying to achieve falls apart. If you have many models (or fits), there's nothing to stop you from calculating the AIC of each one.

Comment: Agreed, on different datasets you cannot (well, you actually *can* but it takes som transformations)

Comment: I'm not sure if I made myself clear. The data I have is diameters of tumors over time. The thing is I do not have the same amount of measurements per tumor, but for all the models I evaluate the same tumors, i.e., I use the same dataset, but the different elements of the dataset do not contain the same number of data point (and I evaluate the error in each of this points).  Can I compute the AIC for that?

Comment: I would still recommend starting a new question with all the details as it may be difficult to convey enough info for us to understand in the comments. For instance, I'm not sure if different number of measurements means that some tumors have the same measurement taken multiple times, or that some tumors just have missing values. But I would suggest that you would just have one single model for all tumors and measurements, and get the AIC of that model. You can then compare it with the AIC of other models fit on all of the data but with different attributes selected.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to @Cameron Chandler; if your RSS=0 it should trigger some alerts since it is 100% overfitting, thus evaluating that model does not make any sense as such. But yes, take the limit of $\log(x), x\rightarrow 0^+$ and notice it goes towards $-\infty$ thus you cannot find a more perfekt model - if you only look at AIC, but you can (almost) not find a worse model if you look at the application.
If you evaluate multiple fits I would simply just ignore those "perfect fits"

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, I am evaluating the AIC for each fit and then I want to take the mean of these values, so if I set it to minus infinity, I will have problems with the mean whenever I have one perfect fit in my dataset

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: The thing is it will be a perfect fit for one of the models but not for the rest, so if I just ignore it, I would be loosing  information. Maybe I should just set it to a big negative number?

Comment: How would you lose information? I would treat it as "missing" since the score provides no information what so ever (other than you are overfitting)

Comment: Ah I see your point, but I am not trying to evaluate overfitting at  the moment since I am fitting the parameters for each tumor. But maybe it is the best solution, thanks.

Comment: I might have phrased that badly (it was not for modelling the overfitting). Let's take another example; if you want to test how a binary classifier performs and you have two classes; C1 and C2. Say you  want to see how many of the elements that are classified as C2 are indeed C2. Lets say your model overfits to C1 then there is no C2, thus devision by 0.  It is the same thing going on here, just with classificaiton instead of regression.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant, but since I am fitting the parameters for each tumor, I think I should also care about the results even if it is overfitting, because actually I am trying to fit them perfectly, not find a generalization for all the tumors. Or is the AIC only valid if you are using the same parameters for all the dataset?

Comment: If you in your question explain what the model is used for (if you are allowed to), and how you are using/planing to use the AIC, we might be able to provide a more correct answer.

Comment: So basically I am comparing a model of differential equations with a linear model and an exponential model. My dataset is measurements of the volume of different tumors, and for each tumor I have a different number of measurements. The two parameters are fitted for each of the tumors separately and I am trying to compare the fitting capacity of the 3 models. But as I evaluate the error at each of the points measured, I don't have a one dimensional y and y_hat (to evaluate the rss, that is why I came up with the solution of taking the mean. Do you think this is a good approach?